# How 3rd party finger print device is working with C#

Tags: c#, fingerprint

I am very new to this topic:-

Suppose If I am using 3rd party finger print sdk,

1. The sdk will provide API's to read data?
2. After scan what data format the device will return, thumb image or
   some index value?
3. Suppose if it is index value where it is stored the thumb images ,
   how the device will identify the image after second scan?
4. The device itself using separate DB for storing the thumb images?
5. Can I expect above queries should be solved by device developer
   manual?

Thanks,
Hemu

Comment: The answer to 1) and 5) is "Yes".  The answer to 2) through 4) is "It depends on the vendor-specific library".

Comment: Is there any developer guide for RealandAPI form sintech vendor

Answer (score 0):

Three major operations need to be followed:

1. **Capture** : Captures the finger
2. **Merge** : Merges the three finger templates  into one (to be used for recording the fingerprint first time)
3. **Verify** : Compare two fingerprint templates (merged one vs newly captured one) and return the score

Scanner doesn't return the index. It should be handled at your software during the capture. More workflow informations can be found at http://camsunit.com/application/html-based-fingerprint-scanner-for-website-authentication-and-attendance.html